# Validating REST messages against Swagger definition

Tags: java, rest, validation, swagger

I'm working within IBM Integration Bus and I found myslef in need of validation of the messages that I recive. Since IIB does not support any kind of validation in this regard, I was wondering if there are any external libraries that could validate those messages for me.

So far, I found this https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-inflector/blob/master/README.md#payload-validation But I was wondering if there are alternatives that might fit my needs a little better.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

One option is the [swagger-request-validator](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator). It lets you validate requests/responses against a Swagger / OpenAPI definition.

There are modules available for integrating with WireMock, Rest Assured, Pact etc., or you can use the validator directly.

Take a look at the [example usages](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/src/master/swagger-request-validator-examples/) for code samples on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the below link in which JSON equivelent XML modeling was used to enable graphical mapping of a JSON message [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.gdm.doc/sm12023_.htm).
In the same manner, you can create an equivelent XML model and switch from JSON to XML domain then run validation using ResetContentDescriptor node. But, I am not sure about the performance. If were you, I would test and compare this solution to yours.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you can use the ResetContentDescriptor to acheive the above scenario. Good luck!